# How do I manipulate string "x" by itself without mixing it in other strings

Tags: python, string, list, character

I'm currently writing a custom file parsing system to convert a specific Txt file to valid JSON and I've been having some difficulty with extracting the character "x" and "y"

I have these lists which all of the possible variables that the txt file could contain.

```
    #Loops through lists to match words and change the paras to be JSON compliant
    for x in linedefParas :
        string = "\"%s\"" % x
        data = data.replace(x, string) 
    for y in sidedefParas :
        string = "\"%s\"" % y
        data = data.replace(y, string)
    for z in vertexParas :
        string = "\"%s\"" % z
        data = data.replace(z, string)
```

This would work fine but vertexParas contain the strings "x" and "y" which is a problem since the x and y is being **picked up in words as well as by itself.**

```
{
x = 880.0;
y = 1288.0;
SECxDis = 90;
}
```

Instead of only wrapping double quotes around the "x" and "y" it will do it in complete words like this

```
{
"x" = 880.0;
"y" = 1288.0
"SEC"x"Dis" = 90;
}
```

The **result I want** to get from this code looks like this :

```
{
"x" = 880.0;
"y" = 1288.0;
"SECxDis" = 90;
}
```

All I want is the "x" and "y" strings by **themselves** to be wrapped in double-quotes. Not the letters in other parts of the strings.

Thanks, Ollie

Comment: change your regex to something like this \sx\s example : https://regex101.com/r/J50xBy/2  tl;dr: only pick up x and y-s that have spaces infront and after them

Comment: Variable and function names should generally follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One conventional way of locating substrings only when they don't appear inside larger words, is to use the "word boundary" feature of regular expressions. Example:

```
import re

s = """{
x = 880.0;
y = 1288.0;
SECxDis = 90;
}"""

linedefParas  = ["x", "y"]
for x in linedefParas :
    s = re.sub(rf"\b{x}\b", lambda match: f'"{match.group()}"', s)

print(s)
```

Result:

```
{
"x" = 880.0;
"y" = 1288.0;
SECxDis = 90;
}
```